# print last date of previous month using date command

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

Like we can print last day and last month in linux using date command, is it possible to print last(end) date of previous and any month of year using 
"date" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get last date of previous month:

```
date -d "-$(date '+%d') days"
Sat Feb 28 02:05:39 EST 2015
```

To get last date from previous month of a **given month** use:

```
date -d "-1 day Mar 1"
Sat Feb 28 00:00:00 EST 2015
```

Comment: What id i want to print the same in ddmmYYYY format ?

Comment: Then you can use: `date -d "-$(date '+%d') days" '+%d-%m-%Y'`